# Apigee: Maven deploy of proxies

Tags: apigee

How can I deploy proxies via a maven build to environments in an org? How could I also promote bundles between environments in an organization through maven .

Comment: This is really broad question. Need to change to specific on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Apigee has released Apigee Deploy Maven Plugin. This tool is open source. You can check it out from here https://github.com/apigee/apigee-deploy-maven-plugin

TL;DR

Checkout [README.md](https://github.com/apigee/apigee-deploy-maven-plugin/tree/master/samples) samples section.

Answer (score 0):

ADT tool can deploy apigee entities such as apiproxy, shared-flow, cache, kvm etc. It's available at https://github.com/ashishkpathak/adt/

Checkout the instruction on downloading (Mac, Linux and Windows) and installing.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30264356)